# what should be the query for creting logical view in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have to write one query in mysql .following is my table of ad_display

```
ad_displaysId |  adv_id | campaign_id | adtypeId | clicked(boolean)
```

i have another table name as advertise which have ad_id

```
ad_id | advertisename
```

cammpaignId is in this table name as camp_table

```
campaign_id | camp_name
```

adtypeId is in this table name as adtype

```
adtypeId | adtype_name
```

now what i want is to create one view which gives me result like this from my ad_display Table

```
advertise_name | camp_name | adtype_name | count_of_clicked | count_of_row
```

here

```
count_of_clicked = count of row where adv_id=? campaignId=? adtypeId=? clicked=true
count_of_row= count of row where adv_id=? campaignId=? adtypeId=?
```

the additional inforamtion i can give is...that in ad_display there is multiple entry with same adv_id same camp_id same ad_typeId with clicked collumn is true or false.

i am totaly new in mysql..so can anyone suggest me query to do this with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create view my_ad_view as
select
    advertise_name,
    camp_name,
    adtype_name,
    sum(clicked) as count_of_clicked,
    count(*) as count_of_row
from ad_display ad
left join advertise a on a.ad_id = ad.ad_displaysId
left join camp_table ct on ct.campaign_id = ad.campaign_id
left join adtype at on at.adtypeId = ad.adtypeId 
group by advertise_name, camp_name, adtype_name
```

Note the nice "trick" of `sum(clicked)`, which works because in mysql `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so summing a boolean counts how many times it is true.